# Looking for a Church-encoding (lambda calculus) to define < , > , !=

Tags: functional-programming, scheme, lisp, lambda-calculus, church-encoding

I have to create some Lambda functions for > , < and !=

I don't have an idea how to , could anyone help me please ?
PS: We just started with Lambda Calculus, so please do not assume any previous knowledge.

Thank you in anticipation !

**Edit** - What I meant was [Arithmetic in Lambda Calculus](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lambda_calculus#Arithmetic_in_lambda_calculus)

**Edit 2** - More accurate : Looking for a Church-encoding (lambda calculus) to define                     `< , > , !=`

---

**Editor's Note**: I think this is what the OP is trying to ask:

I am trying to implement the following operations in the untyped lambda calculus using Church encoding:

1. Greater than (`GT` or `>`).
2. Lesser than (`LT` or `<`).
3. Not equal to (`NE` or `!=`).

I already know how to implement the following:

1. Boolean true (`TRUE` or `λx.λy.x`).
2. Boolean false (`FALSE` or `λx.λy.y`).
3. Logical and (`AND` or `λp.λq.p q p`).
4. Logical or (`OR` or `λp.λq.p p q`).
5. Logical not (`NOT` or `λp.λa.λb.p b a`).

How would you write the `GT`, `LT` and `NE` functions in the untyped lambda calculus?

Comment: What does "create lambda function for >" mean? A lambda that just wraps the operator? What on earth would be the point of that?

Comment: @SebastianRedl: The OP seems to be (sorry if I'm wrong) not very used to haskell and might not know that <, > and /= are just normal functions.

Comment: So basically, he might just want the section `(<)`, which can be used as a normal function.

Comment: We don't know what he wants.

Comment: a Lambda for ">": `(\a b -> a > b)`. Can you create the other two now?

Comment: Meh, he prolly changed the meaning w/o even knowing that and the assignment was 90% about sections.

Comment: Oh , let me explain that by an example for the AND-Function , written as Lambda:
lambdax x. lambda y . xy F  ( F = lambda x. lambda y . y)
We are not in Haskell , its just for formal purposes

Comment: For those who still do not know what my question is about : http://simple.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lambda_calculus 
Keyword: LAMBDA CALCULUS

Comment: @user2938633 Oh we know what a lambda is, thank you very much. But what the hell are you asking?

Comment: Well , look at my and function written in lambda calculus. Now , I am not looking for AND else I am looking for >. I wanna write a lambda calculus for >, in the same way how I wrote AND as lambda calculus

Comment: Okay, let us start with this question: How would you define the and operator ^ in lambda calculus without using Haskell ?

Comment: It sounds like the OP is referring to http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lambda_calculus#Arithmetic_in_lambda_calculus

Comment: Exactly , thank you very much Chris Taylor

Comment: a > b == (a-b) > 0. Does that help?

Comment: Unfortunately not , I have to write in arithmetic "style" , please check my link posted in the question ( will refer to wikipedia)

Comment: did you read that linked section until its end? Does it have a PRED function? What does it say about the SUB function and its return value in case m > n and otherwise? Does the next section have a function ISZERO?

Comment: @user2938633 So what you want is the *Church enconding* of the `<`, `>` and `!=` operators. I suggest you change your question to clarify that. Also, not sure why you tagged this question with Haskell, since there's nothing Haskell specific here.

Comment: It does not have a pred function. I just have to define < > and != operators with church enconding (lamda calculus)

Comment: Please look to the edited question. It clearifies everything.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You also need the implementation of natural numbers. That's what you're going to write comparision operators for, isn't it.

I think that I remember the implementation of natural numbers. A number *n* is represented as a function taking a function *f* and a value *x*, and applying *f*  *n* times on *x*.

```
zero = λf . λx . x
succ = λn . λf . λx . n f (f x)
```

Answer (score 5):

Using ["An Introduction To Functional Programming Through Lambda Calculus"](http://cs.fit.edu/~ryan/library/functional_programming/gjm.lambook88.pdf) by Greg Michaelson

Starting with

> Section 4.8.3. Comparison
>
> There are a number of ways of defining equality between numbers. One
>   approach is to notice that the difference between two equal numbers is
>   zero. However, if we subtract a number from a smaller number we also
>   get zero so we need to find the absolute difference between them; the
>   difference regardless of the order of comparison. To find the absolute
>   difference between two numbers, add the difference between the first
>   and the second to the difference between the second and the first:
>
> def abs_diff x y = add (sub x y) (sub y x)
>
> If they are both the same then the absolute differences will be zero
>   because the result of taking each from the other will be zero. If the
>   first is greater than the second then the absolute difference will be
>   the first minus the second because the second minus the first will be
>   zero. Similarly, if the second is greater than the first then the
>   difference will be the second minus the first because the first minus
>   the second will be zero.
>
> Thus, we can define:
>
> def equal x y = iszero (abs_diff x y)
>
> We can also use subtraction to define arithmetic inequalities. For
>   example, a number is greater than another if subtracting the second
>   from the first gives a non-zero result:
>
> def greater x y = not (iszero (sub x y))

Less is defined in the solutions to exercises section in the back.

> def less x y = greater y x

Now using the book in the link just find all of the subordinate functions and you will have =, >, <. While the book does not define != it should be obvious.

EDIT

Per comment by WillNess

> 4.8.2. Subtraction
>
> To find the difference between two numbers, find the difference between the numbers after decrementing both. The difference between a number and zero is the number:
>
> rec sub x y =
>     if iszero y
>     then x
>     else sub (pred x) (pred y)

Please note `"Now using the book in the link just find all of the subordinate functions".`

I don't plan on hunting down all of the subordinate functions and listing them here because they would explode into recreating many functions here. I have read and worked through portions of the book and it is comprehensive enough that I was not lacking for info.

Comment: yes but what is `sub`? the OP says they don't even have `pred` function. Thanks for the link. :)

Answer (score 2):

The Wikipedia article on Church encoding has a section on [predicates](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Church_encoding#Predicates) that covers `EQ` and `LEQ`